# Payload is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-saga, laravel-api

I'm a PHP/Laravel mid-level developer. I'm totally a noob when it comes to *react.js*. Now I know that react uses API's and stuff to show data when it comes to laravel backend. I am used to traditional *HTML, CSS, JS, Bootstrap, Ajax* and whatsoever. I have a simple task to login a user from react through laravel backend. I'v created the APIs for that task and they're working totally fine and somehow I got lucky and attached those APIs *ALL BY MYSELF (with a little research, of course)*. Now whenever I try to signin, I receive the usual data through an axios request to backend and have it in a variable `signInUser`. Now when I try to pass that data to other action function it's going `undefined` somehow. Here's my code so that you can understand what I'm trying to achieve:

**Components\SignIn.js**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
}

componentDidUpdate() {
     if (this.props.showMessage) {
         setTimeout(() => {
             this.props.hideMessage();
         }, 100);
     }
     if (this.props.authUser !== null) {
         this.props.history.push('/');
     }
}

render() {
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    const {showMessage, loader, alertMessage} = this.props;
    return (
        // other components and stuff...
        <Button onClick={() => { this.props.showAuthLoader(); this.props.userSignIn({email, password});}} variant="contained" color="primary">
            <IntlMessages id="appModule.signIn"/>
        </Button>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
    const {loader, alertMessage, showMessage, authUser} = auth;
    return {loader, alertMessage, showMessage, authUser}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    userSignIn,
    hideMessage,
    showAuthLoader
})(SignIn);
```

**Sagas\Auth.js**

```
const signInUserWithEmailPasswordRequest = async (email, password) =>
    await axios.post('auth/login', {email: email, password: password})
    .then(authUser => authUser)
    .catch(err => err);

function* signInUserWithEmailPassword({payload}) {
    const {email, password} = payload;
    try {
        const signInUser = yield call(signInUserWithEmailPasswordRequest, email, password);
        if (signInUser.message) {
            yield put(showAuthMessage(signInUser.message));
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('user_id', signInUser.data.user.u_id);
            yield put(userSignInSuccess(signInUser.data.user.u_id));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(showAuthMessage(error));
    }
}

export function* signInUser() {
    yield takeEvery(SIGNIN_USER, signInUserWithEmailPassword);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([fork(signInUser),
    // couple of other functions...
    );
}
```

**actions\Auth.js**

```
export const userSignIn = (user) => {
    return {
        type: SIGNIN_USER,
        payload: user
    };
};

export const userSignInSuccess = (authUser) => {
    console.log(authUser); // It's printing undefined, I don't know why?!
    return {
        type: SIGNIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: authUser
    }
};
```

**reducers\Auth.js**

```
const INIT_STATE = {
    loader: false,
    alertMessage: '',
    showMessage: false,
    initURL: '',
    authUser: localStorage.getItem('user_id'),
};

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGNIN_USER_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loader: false,
                authUser: action.payload
            }
        }

        case INIT_URL: {
            return {
                ...state,
                initURL: action.payload
            }
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**P.s**: *It's a purchased react.js template (not my code).*

Comment: Oh, do you mean that `signInUser` is undefined, or what variable exactly are you getting undefined on?

Comment: Are you using `connect` in your SignIn component; could you show more of SignIn in that case? I guess the error you are experiencing is not due to the code you have posted

Comment: @Patrick Yep, it's using `connect`. I'm sorry I didn't post that code. I'm updating my question with more code. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: No the `signInUser` is not `undefined`. It has `{email: 'some email', password: 'some password'}` in it. But when I try to send that using `yield put(userSignInSuccess(signInUser.data.user.u_id));` the action in **action\Auth.js** is receiving undefined. To be specific:
`export const userSignInSuccess = (authUser) => {
    console.log(authUser); // It's printing undefined, I don't know why?!`

Comment: so you're saying that `localStorage.setItem()` *does* save a value, but your call to userSignInSuccess is getting undefined? What does a call to `console.log(signInUser.data.user)` print before you call that method?

Comment: Now that you mentioned, I've checked the `localStorage.getItem('user_id');`, it's also returning undefined. I did a logging to sniff out the data flow and found that in the `try` scope `const signInuser` has the data, but as soon as it enters the `else` block it loses it's entire data and become `undefined`.
*P.s: I've posted the logging code below, please check.*

Comment: `try {
    const signInUser = yield call(signInUserWithEmailPasswordRequest, email, password);
    console.log(signInUser); // Has value
    if (signInUser.message) {
      yield put(showAuthMessage(signInUser.message));
    } else {
      console.log(signInUser.data.user.u_id); // undefined
      localStorage.setItem('user_id', signInUser.data.user.u_id);
      let a = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
      console.log("localstorage: "+a); // undefined
      console.log(signInUser.data.user.u_id); // undef
      yield put(userSignInSuccess(signInUser.data.user.u_id));
    }
  }`

Comment: Can you unpack `signInUser` and use the data property in that case? `const signInUser = yield call(/*as before*/); const data = signInUser.data; /* use data and see if that works */`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. By unpacking the `signInUser` and using it's `.data` property I came to know that user id is defined under the key of `id`. I sent this id as `u_id` from the api but somehow it's sending it as `id` instead. It's all working perfectly now. Thanks again man. Please submit an answer so that I can mark it as accepted!

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out. I can post an answer but if it turned out as a typo there's not much of an answer to give, other than giving some pointers in how to look for similar errors if encountered again :) If you'd like you can also answer the question yourself and mark it as an answer